# How to reproject a set of data in Python to 4326?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, numpy, rasterio

I need to reproject a set of data in a numpy array with a shape of (121, 160) with

```
crs='+proj=merc +units=meters +a=6370000.0 +b=6370000.0 +lon_0=-76.0100021362 +lat_ts=20.3180007935 +nadgrids=@null'
```

To crs="epsg:4326" in the location

```
Upper Left  ( -96.5979538,   5.2124481) ( 96d35'52.63"W,  5d12'44.81"N)
Lower Left  ( -96.5979538,  34.0865555) ( 96d35'52.63"W, 34d 5'11.60"N)
Upper Right ( -55.4220505,   5.2124481) ( 55d25'19.38"W,  5d12'44.81"N)
Lower Right ( -55.4220505,  34.0865555) ( 55d25'19.38"W, 34d 5'11.60"N)
Center      ( -76.0100021,  19.6495018) ( 76d 0'36.01"W, 19d38'58.21"N)
```

I am currently doing

```
    crs4326 = CRS.from_string('epsg:4326')
    affine = from_origin(x.min(), y.max(), xLength/xCellCount, yLength/yCellCount)

    dstTransform, width, heigth = calculate_default_transform(
        originCRS,
        crs4326,
        xCellCount,
        yCellCount,
        x.min(),
        y.min(),
        x.max(),
        y.max()
    )

    destination = np.zeros((heigth, width), np.float32)
    reproject(
        var,
        destination,
        src_transform=affine,
        dst_transform=dstTransform,
        src_crs=netcdfAttributes['crs'],
        dst_crs=crs4326,
        resampling=Resampling.nearest
    )
```

But for some reason the image deforms look at the bottom

[image]

Comment: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reproject.html

Comment: @MarceloVilla please read again the post I have updated it

Comment: There is something strange about the extent of your data... Where is it supposed to be in the world? Your extent is tiny and near Null Island in Africa with values such as `0d 0' 2.46"W,  0d 0' 0.64"N`. The x,y values look like they could be longitudes and latitudes already, and that would correpond to an extent in North/Central America.

Comment: @FSimardGIS, could you read the question again? I have updated it